# Looking for an OpenPGP implementation in Lua

Tags: lua, pgp, openpgp, luau

Are there any OpenPGP implementations in Lua? I could only find one (https://github.com/pvthuyet/LuaOpenPGP) but it's in C++ and i need one in pure Lua. Does anyone have it?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use external C libraries, you may try to use RNP lib (https://github.com/rnpgp/rnp/) via the lua's FFI: https://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html
Or, could you please explain why do you require pure Lua implementation?